# Display a block in a page

Tags: views, 6, blocks

I have a block created with Views that I want to display in a node where "PHP filter" is enabled. How can I display the content of that block?

All the examples I can find seem to be for Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     $block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'ViewName-DisplayId');
     echo $block['content']['#markup'];
```

Parameters in [module_invoke](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke):

1. module to call: 'views'
2. hook to call, in this case 'block_view'
3. View name and display id of the block, separated by an hyphen. For example 'testview-block_1'

The display id of the block it will show only when hovering the mouse over the "Block" word in the Views page of the Block. You will see an url like this: http:///admin/structure/views/nojs/display/testview/**block_1**
The **block_1** is the display id in this case.

Comment: I got it working... but it won't "show" when anon... if I log out, it's a blank page.

Comment: It's with both of my view_blocks... hrm....

Comment: @WernerCD Did you verify the view is visible to anonymous users?

Comment: Found out the issue. Awesome :) The issue is it was making the nodes unpublished... I'm a tard.

Comment: @corbacho dear what if i want to display a custom built block of another module into my custom built page? i want to display the "disqus'" disqus_comments block into my custom built page

Comment: @Mutjaba it's better u open a new question with more details. Or google it http://www.google.com/search?q=module_invoke+block&hl=en